# How to set Data coding to 3 in kannel

Tags: kannel, bulksms

I need to set data_coding value in kannel to 3. But I cant figure out how to do that. I have tried all options available.

I have found that to set dcs to 3 we must set coding to 2 and use LATIN1 charset which I am using but still i get data_coding as 8 and not 3.
Can anyone tell me how to do this.

We can use only three values in coding section that is 0,1 and 2

0 sets data_coding to 0
1 sets it to 4
2 sets it to 8

How to set it to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting mwi & mclass & compress fields in send-sms url.
Note:- Only one out of mwi or mclass can be set.

Let me know if it worked